# Possible to TRIM multiple criteria from a single column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

newbie here. There are station names in a column that have extra characters at the end. I'd like to trim them in PostgreSQL.

For example, this works to remove ' (Temp)' at the end.

```
   SELECT
   station_name,
   RTRIM(station_name,' (Temp)')     
   FROM station_data
```

I would also like to remove ' - SW' as well.

Example data can look something like this:

```
    north_station
    east_station
    south_station
    south_station (Temp)
    south_station - SW
```

Ideal result would look like this:

```
   north_station
   east_station
   south_station
   south_station
   south_station
```

I've tried using CASE WHEN or OR with RTRIM but either the setup/order is wrong or maybe it can't be used in conjunction? Thank you.

Comment: `RTRIM(RTRIM(station_name,' (Temp)'), ' - SW')`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REPLACE function. This function lets you replace a specific substring with another substring. By using REPLACE twice in a row, you can remove both ' (Temp)' and ' - SW' from the station names. It's like peeling off two layers: first, you remove ' (Temp)', and then you remove ' - SW'. This leaves you with the cleaned-up station names that you're looking for.

`SELECT station_name, REPLACE(REPLACE(station_name, ' (Temp)', ''), ' - SW', '') as trimmed_station_name FROM station_data;`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: That will become extremely unhandy if further texts appear that should be removed

Comment: This worked, thank you! Also got the case working with CASE WHEN start_station ~ ' - SW$' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(start_station, ' - SW$', '') ELSE start_station AS trimmed_station

Answer (score 1):

**If** the data always has exactly this form, i.e. first a string with the name of the station, then a space, then another string with some additional information, we can use `SPLIT_PART` to select the part before the first space only:

```
SELECT
  station_name, 
  SPLIT_PART(station_name, ' ', 1) AS newStationName
FROM station_data;
```

Here a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4RTHBGxN) based on your sample data.

If you have further use cases and need a more complex solution, please extend the question to show those use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the station names be always single words, you could use the following regex replacement approach:

```sql
SELECT station_name, REGEXP_REPLACE(station_name, ' .*', '') AS station_name_out
FROM station_data;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the REGEXP_REPLACE func to remove both ' (Temp)' and ' - SW' from the end of station names. Try out this code:

```
SELECT station_name, 
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(station_name, ' \\(Temp\\)$', ''), ' - SW$', '') AS cleaned_station_name
FROM station_data;
```